# Impliment Slidingdrawer with viewpager where slidingdrawer resides on the viewpager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, slidingdrawer, android-navigation

[image]

I want to display a Viewpager with slidingdrawer.Viewpager is used to scroll the images and on top of that viewpager I want to place one sliding drawer(top to button).

i attached my sample code. If you have any idea about how to implement this screen, please help me out.

- ```
  android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:orientation="vertical" >

  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/TextView01"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
      android:text="Infra2Apps"
      android:textColor="#ffffff"
      android:textSize="9pt" />

  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/textView1"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginLeft="6dip"
      android:text="Sales and Marketing Resources"
      android:textColor="#ffffff"
      android:textStyle="bold"
      android:typeface="sans" />
  ```

  ```
  <LinearLayout
      android:id="@+id/handle"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

      <ImageView
          android:id="@+id/imageView"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:src="@drawable/arrow" />
  </LinearLayout>

  <ImageView
      android:id="@+id/content"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:background="#FF0000"
      android:src="@drawable/love" />
  ```

  ```
  <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
      android:id="@+android:id/viewpager"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
  ```

  ```
  <ImageView
      android:id="@+id/settings"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="25dp"
      android:src="@drawable/settings" />

  <ImageView
      android:id="@+id/search"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="24dp"
      android:src="@drawable/searchbutton" />

  <ImageView
      android:id="@+id/refresh"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="27dp"
      android:src="@drawable/refreshrest" />

  <ImageView
      android:id="@+id/question"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="26dp"
      android:src="@drawable/questionmark" />
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Use a frame layout and use drawer for a fixed width and height.

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/middle_ll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/view_pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <SlidingDrawer
        android:id="@+id/option_menu"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/drawer_top_height"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:content="@+id/content"
        android:handle="@+id/handle"
        android:rotation="180" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:rotation="180" >

            <include
                android:id="@+id/menu_pop_down"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                layout="@layout/menu_layout"
                android:visibility="visible" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/handle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:rotation="180" >

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:src="@drawable/date_picker_icon" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </SlidingDrawer>

</FrameLayout>
```